# Vertical Navigation - How can I keep the nav menu contents static, even on child pages?

Tags: razor, sitefinity, sitefinity-10

We are using Sitefinity 11 and MVC.  We are trying to use just one template for the main heading pages that reside just under the root of the site.  On that template, we'd intend to use a vertical navbar (using the included Sitefinity navbar widget set to the Vertical view, its Bootstrap 4) which will reside on the left side of the page.

We want the navigation to show the top most page of that section (which we have enabled by turning "ShowParentPage" to True, and display child pages up to 3 levels deep (including the top page...so child and grand child pages).  The tricky part is that we'd like for it to stay the same, even when the user navigates into one of the child pages and always show that top level with the two sub levels.  There is no built in functionality for this currently, and the closest option to use is to set the widget to always show current page and children.  But again, this results in it setting the current page to the top instead.

There are only going to be three or four of these top level pages under the home page, so if push comes to shove, we could create a different template for each section of the site, and then just set the navigation widget to always default to the top page of that section which is another built in option on the navigation widget, but this seems like it would result in duplicated effort.

I've been trying to modify the NavigationView.Vertical razor html view to achieve our desired result, but I am having no luck.  My thought, is that if I could check to see if the parent page, or parent of the parent page has a certain page title (which should remain pretty static over time, although yeah I know this can lead to risk of the page name is changed), then set that as the active node, and then have the code do what it is doing already, which is to loop through the child pages and write them to the navigation menu.

This is a snippet of the default code on the view:

```
@model Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.Navigation.Mvc.Models.INavigationModel

<div class="@Model.CssClass">
    <nav>

            <ul class="nav flex-column navbar-child-custom">
                @foreach (var node in Model.Nodes)
                {
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link @GetClass(node)" href="@node.Url" target="@node.LinkTarget">@node.Title</a>
                        @RenderSubLevelsRecursive(node)
                    </li>

                }
            </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

If I could somehow set that node in the for-each loop to the top most parent page, then I could just let it do it's thing and it would work, but I don't know of a proper way to do this.

Any help or suggestions are much appreciated!

EDIT:  I've attached some images which shows the page hierarchy (which you can see has Members, Retirees, and Employers as the three top level pages I'm referring to), the selection used in the template, and then also the result on the page when you are on the members page, and then what happens to the left nav when you are on the Pensions page which is just under Members.  In this case, we want the navigation to remain the same, as if you were on the Members page.

[Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6h24.png)

[Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x13VM.png)

[Members page View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSSyR.png)

[Pension Page View (child of Members)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcElV.png)

Comment: What pages did you select to show in the vertical nav? Is it all pages or is it all pages under a particular page? Can you add some screenshots of the Page hierarchy and how it looks like currently and the desired outcome?

Comment: I have added four screen shots.  Hopefully this makes everything clearer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the "All Pages under a Particular Page" option and select the Members page.

This, it will always show the child pages of the Members page.

Having the ShowParentPage to True (as you already have) will display the Members page as well.

Comment: This works for any page under the members section of the site, but for any other section of the site (Retirees, Employers) would require a different navbar widget, with the respective top page of that section selected, thus requiring a separate page template for each section (since the navbar is built into the template).  So while this is a solution (which I mentioned in my original post), it's not quite what we are looking for.

Comment: I understand. Well, having multiple page templates is not such a terrible idea, is it? Especially when they inherit each other, e.g. you select the Members page in Template1 and make the widget Editable on Pages. Then create Template2 based on Template1 and edit the widget and select all pages under Retirees page, etc.

Comment: Yes, it will do the job. I think we will use that solution for now.  In the future once perhaps I will find a solution for achieving what I set out to do in my question.  Thanks.